# Objective C : how to convert NSString to UInt8 array

Tags: ios, arrays, nsstring

I had one tag in my code as below

```
static const UInt8 publicKeyIdentifier[] = "com.example.zone\0";
Now in place of "com.example.zone" i need to use following String "nameWithZoneId" 

NSString id = @"123456";
NSString *nameWithZoneId = [@"com.example.zone" stringByAppendingString:id];
```

so i can use tag as dynamic way eg. "com.example.zone123456\0";
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is VERY unclear what you are asking! VERY! What are you trying to do exactly? Your code as of now has nothing dynamic in it, so there is no reason not just DO what you are trying.

Comment: @luk2302 i clearly mention which string i wanna use as tag, i had just given one example, variable id value is dynamic.

Comment: Judging by the amount of responses and reactions it is **NOT** clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Tag` class to keep count of the tag value for each specified *identifier* (`"com.example.zone"` in your example).

Tag.h:

```
@interface Tag : NSObject
+ (NSString *)nextTagForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
@end
```

Tag.m:

```
static NSMutableDictionary *_identifiers = nil;

@implementation Tag

+ (NSString *)nextTagForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    if (_identifiers == nil)
        _identifiers = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    NSUInteger value = [_identifiers[identifier] unsignedInteger] + 1;
    _identifiers[identifier] = @(value);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%lu", identifier, value];
}

@end
```

And you would use it like this:

```
NSString *nameWithZoneId = [Tag nextTagForIdentifier:@"com.example.zone"];
```

Comment: thank you for answer but i do not need to make new class i just need to convert NSString String into UInt8 array object.

Comment: as currently i'm using that variable as static const UInt8 publicKeyIdentifier[] = "com.example.zone\0";